# Plex Media Server, unable to load libraries

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have just installed PMS on my RPI3 B, after some issues I can manage the server fro the web gui, but I can not load any libraries.
As you can see from the screenshot it is not possible to continue further as the drop-down menu for the language selection does not work.

[image: pms]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Raspberry Pi-specific question.

Comment: So tell me where to move...

Comment: Have you considered the [Plex Forums](https://forums.plex.tv/)? Specifically the [Media Server > Desktop section](https://forums.plex.tv/c/plex-media-server/computers/21).

Comment: Just wRitten, int this forum. I'm trying to figure out if it's a problem related to the PMS version or something missing in the my PI